# How can I use thumbpdf (perltex) with arara?

Tags: arara, thumbpdf

Good evening, as to my knowledge there is no `arara-perltex`-rule, so I can not use `thumbpdf`-package with arara.

My background Idea is: using individual thumbnails, like the "yellow thumnail" in the picture, in the pdf-viewer (AdobeReader) ;)

[image]

Comment: What does a normal build chain look like with `thumbpdf`?

Comment: Hi! As @Sean mentioned, do you have a sample `.tex` document + your compilation workflow? From the `thumbpdf` README, I can get an idea of what to do, but we need your feedback. `:)`

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry, my previous tries with `thumbpdf` had have not really succes. So my hope was (is!), if there is an arara-rule (for `thumbpdf`, `perltex`), from the experts - I could research the potential of this package ;)

Comment: @cis: If you are having problems with running `thumbpdf`, then state the problems, error messages etc. Using a wrapper like `arara` will not solve the underlying problems.